# Display one random thumbnail image per album PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

This is related to this question: [Load Array via nested foreach loops in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873869/load-array-via-nested-foreach-loops-in-php)

Currently, I have this set of nested `foreach` loops:

```
$subfolders = glob($directory);
foreach($subfolders as $subfolder) {
    $photos = glob($subfolder.'/*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]');
    foreach($photos as $photo) {
        $thumbnail = $subfolder.'/thumbs/'.$photoname[0].'_thumb.jpg';
        $thumb = '<img src="'.$thumbnail.'" class="thumb_image">';
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is, in another `foreach($subfolders as $subfolder)` loop further down the page, load one random `$thumb` per `$subfolder`.  I tried to do it using a multi-dimensional array as you can see in my previous  question but apparently that won't work.  What other ways can I accomplish this?

Comment: why not give unique ids to the arrays?

Comment: @Esq Because I am not smart enough to know how to do that...

Comment: how many subfolders do you have?

Comment: @Esq x.  Right now there's 9, but there could be 7 or 20 or 1 tomorrow...

Comment: //// get random j

// $thumbnail = $subfolder[i].'/thumbs/'.$photoname[j].'_thumb.jpg';


i dont see a reason why something like this wont work ^

Comment: It's for an album listing, so I need one random thumbnail for each subfolder... But I might be able to work with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a neater version of what I meant:

```
$subfolders = glob($directory);
foreach($subfolders as $subfolderNo) {
    $photos = glob($subfolderNo.'/*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]');
    // generate the $randomNo, random from 0 to $photo.size() 
    $thumbnail = $subfolderNo.'/thumbs/'.$photoname[$randomNo].'_thumb.jpg';
    $thumb = '<img src="'.$thumbnail.'" class="thumb_image">';
}
```